# Checking min max without using function or list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer, minmax

```
min1=0
max1=0

while True:
    num=input("enter a number")
    if (num=='done'):
        break
    elif (num.isdigit()==False):
        print("sorry enter integers or done")
    elif (int(num)>max1):
        max1=num
    elif (int(num)<min1):
        min1=num
print(max1)
print(min1)
```

This is throwing error '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'. I cannot take integer input as I have to break when the user enters done. Also, I have to account for non-integer values entered by user. How to rectify this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this is to convert the input to an integer once rather than using `int(num)` multiple times throughout the code.
This makes it easier to read later on.

An example of this is is changing

`elif (num.isdigit()==False):`

to

`elif (num.isdigit()==True):` or `elif (num.isdigit())` (they do the same thing).

Then you can convert the string to an integer with
`num = int(num)`

Example:

```
min1=0
max1=0

while True:
    num=input("enter a number")
    if (num=='done'):
        break
    if num.isdigit():
        num = int(num)
    else:
        print("sorry enter integers or done")
        continue
    if (num>max1):
        max1=num
    elif (num<min1):
        min1=num
print(max1)
print(min1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume `num='5'`. Then `elif (int(num)>max1):` holds and you assign `'5'` to `max1`. In the next iteration, `max1` is a string and therefore you get an error. The solution is - `max1=int(num)` (and same for `min1`).